# MKMapPoint (iOS) equivalent on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

A colleague and I are working on a project that involves drawing a static grid over a Google Map.  The problem is that he is using MKMapPoint for iOS, and I can't find anything similar for Android... seems like I can only use longitude and latitude. It essentially sets x0,y0 as the top left point on the map.
Does anything like this exist for Android?

Comment: Yes, still searching for an answer unfortunately.

Comment: can you explain me the what you want exactly